# How to I decode the headers of a message using Gmail-API using Java?

Tags: java, android, gmail-api

I am working on a fragment in android studio whose purpose is to display To/From, Subject, and the body of the message. So far, I am able to retrieve, decode, and display the body. I tried using a similar method for the headers but for some reason it isn't decoding properly, or my method calls aren't getting the correct information. Here is the code I am working with:

```
     String user = "me";
     String query = "in:inbox is:unread";
     textView.setText("Inbox");
     ListMessagesResponse messageResponse =
            mService.users().messages().list(user).setQ(query).setMaxResults(Long.valueOf(1)).execute();

        List<Message> messages = messageResponse.getMessages();

        for(Message message : messages){
            Message message2 = mService.users().messages().get(user, message.getId()).execute();

            //Get Headers
            byte[] headerBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(message2.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getHeaders().get(0).getName().toString().trim()); // get headers
            String header = new String(headerBytes, "UTF-8");

            //Get Body
            byte[] bodyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(message2.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getBody().getData().trim().toString()); // get body
            String body = new String(bodyBytes, "UTF-8");

            messageList.add(header);
            messageList.add(body);
        }
        return messageList;
```

The section under `// get body` works. But the section under `//Get Headers` returns data with weird symbols which include black diamonds with white question marks inside and letters in random order. I have tried many different combinations and orders for the method calls in the `Base64.decodeBase64` statement for `headerBytes` but wasn't able to succeed. Is there something I am missing?

Edit: I looked at the gmail-api documentation on the google developers site and I still am confused on how the header information is stored and how to retrieve specific things such as To, From, and Subject. That might be my problem since I may not be targeting the correct data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I [list messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it) and [get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#try-it) the first one, we can see what the message looks like:

**Request**

```
format = metadata
metadataHeaders = From,To,Subject
fields = payload/headers

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/15339f3d12042fec?format=metadata&metadataHeaders=To&metadataHeaders=From&metadataHeaders=Subject&fields=payload%2Fheaders&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "payload": {
  "headers": [
   {
    "name": "To",
    "value": "Emil <emtholin@gmail.com>"
   },
   {
    "name": "From",
    "value": "\"BernieSanders.com\" <info@berniesanders.com>"
   },
   {
    "name": "Subject",
    "value": "5,000,000"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

As you can see, the values you are looking for are in the headers. You just have to sort them out in Java and you are done. The headers are not encoded like the body, so there is no need to do any decoding.

Comment: Well I just feel really silly now. Thank you for your answer. It helped me realize that my problem was with trying to decode the header. I don't need to decode it. The following line worked: `String h = message2.getPayload().getHeaders().get(5).getValue().toString();` which is exactly what you mentioned by sorting them out in Java. Thank you. (Second time you've helped me!).